# Showing groups are elementary abelian and have the same order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and $p$ a prime. Let $A^{p}=\{a^p\mid a\in A\}$ and $A_p=\{x\mid x^p=1\}$. Prove that $A/A^p\cong A_p$ (Show that they are both elementary abelian and they have the same order).

I know that to show a group is elementary abelian, I need to show that any nontrivial element has order $p$. This is obvious for $A_p$, but the elements of $A/A^p$ are left cosets of $A$ of the form $aA^p$, so how do we find $|aA^p|$?

As for showing $|A/A^p|=\frac{|A|}{|A^p|}=|A_p|$, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Since $A$ is abelian $\varphi(a) = a^p$  is a surjective morphism $A \to A^p$ thus $A^p \cong A/\ker(\varphi)$ ([1st isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem))

Comment: The elements of $A/A^p$ are of the form $a A^p$ ($=  A^p a$ since $A^p$ is normal) not $a^p A$.

Comment: A finite Abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order. So you can show that you can assume that A is a cyclic group of order $p^n$ for some $n>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @StephenMeskin and reuns but I'm still not sure where to go from there..